# Isolating the divergences in the stress energy tensor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In DeWitt's report "Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime" ([B. S. DeWitt, Phys. Rep. 19C, 292 (1975)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu//abs/1975PhR....19..295D)), he states that in Eq.(175)

$$\langle in, vac| T^{\mu\nu}|in,vac\rangle = 2 \frac{\delta W}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} - i \sum_{i,j} \Lambda_{ij}T^{\mu\nu}(u_{\rm in}{}_{i*},u_{\rm in}{}_{j*})$$

the second term in the RHS is composed of only finite terms thus only the first term contains divergences, but doesn't give any justification. Why is the second term finite?